# How to make custom field usable for users in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to make for example text area custom field and display it on post where user that wrote that post would be able input some value in that text area and save it?

I have tried advanced custom fields plugin but eather lack of knowledge or plugin possibilities led to fail because i could only create custom field that would appear in wordpress admin area and display that custom field in post.

Comment: Try [CMB2](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2) although it initially looks like you need to know a lot of code to make it work its actually very easy to use and allows front end forms

Comment: @Rich Thank you for your reply now at least i have some ways to do it , but maybe you have some suggestions which has their own interface on wp-admin?

Comment: @Rich : u can acheive it via advance custom field plugin. and then call that field into ur post template to display.

ex: <?php $var=get_post_meta($post->ID, "fieldname", true); ?>

Comment: @Montiyago I dont think that in that case person would be able to fill that field himself in that post becauxse this is only displaying custom field that is already filled in wordpress admin area

Comment: @Danniel:when a personwill make post he can fill this from backend.nd u can show it in frontend.though person can not fill it from frontend.